# Invoke Alexa device from lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am new in Alexa development. I have successfully create an Alexa skill with AWS lambda function and Node.js code. It's working fine with my Alexa echo plus device.

e.g : Alexa, open **"mySampleApp"**

Now, I need to invoke Alexa device to make it speak via from another lambda function. 
Is it possible?

e.g: I  just execute my lambda function. 
 I need to make speech output via my Alexa echo plus device.

Comment: You mean another Lambda function with the same skill or call another Lambda from a Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to trigger a notification (make speech output) from outside of your skill; if that's it, then it's not possible YET. 
Push notifications have been a feature people have been aksing for a while and they recently announced that are comming soon, see: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned